# How to format a calendar based on user input in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I have an assignment in which the user is asked the start date of the month (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday etc).

The following is the code that I have tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalendarMonth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CalendarMonth().runApp();
    }

    void runApp() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the start day: ");
        int startDay = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of days: ");
        int daysMonth = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");
        System.out.println("---\t---\t---\t---\t---\t---\t---\t");

        //determine starting day with spaces
        startDay%=7;
        //System.out.println("startDay value is " + startDay);
        for(int i = 0; i<=startDay;i++){
            System.out.print("X"); //prints a space for each empty day
        }

        for(int j = 1; j <= daysMonth; j++){
            if (j < 10){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            if (startDay%7 == 0){
                System.out.print( j + "\n");
            }

            else{
                System.out.print(j + "\t");
            }
            startDay++;

        }
        }

    }
```

This is the **expected** output:

```
Enter the start day: 3
Enter the number of days: 30
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- 
             1   2   3   4  
 5   6   7   8   9  10  11
12  13  14  15  16  17  18
19  20  21  22  23  24  25
26  27  28  29  30
```

This is the actual output:

```
Enter the start day: 3
Enter the number of days: 30
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- 
XXXX 1   2   3   4   5
 6   7   8   9  10  11  12
13  14  15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24  25  26
27  28  29  30
```

The XXXX in the first row of the calendar is just a placeholder until I can figure out how to format it. I've been working on this for many hours, I suppose I need help possibly with an explanation if generous. If not, I'll learn as much as I can from the code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Step through your program using the debugger. You'll see that you have two off-by-one errors, one where you print the X's, and one in deciding where to print a newline.

Comment: For empty days you can use `System.out.print(" ".repeat(4*startDay));` As each column has 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the week starts at 0 and ends at 6, a new week should start a new line on the 7th iteration, which is when startDay is at 6.

I changed the code to:

```
if (startDay%7 == 6){
                System.out.print( j + "\n");
            }
```

Getting the remainder of the startDay divided by 7, and if it equals to 6 (which is the end of the week), make the code do a newline.